# error : couldn't read row 0 , col -1 from cursorWindow make sure the cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it?

Tags: android

```
private void populateQuestionList() {
    int QuestionTableSubjectId = questionModelObject.getSubjectId();
    ArrayList<QuestionModel> questionArrayList = QuestionManager.getQuestionManager(this).getQuestionBySubjectID(QuestionTableSubjectId);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    for (int i = 0; i < questionArrayList.size(); i++) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ctrl_list_row, null);
        row.setOnClickListener(this);
        TextView questionTV = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_ctrl_name);
        String question = questionArrayList.get(i).getQuestion();
        questionTV.setText(question);
        row.setTag(questionArrayList.get(i));
        questionList.addView(row);
    }
}
```

This method for show question in list calling method `getQuestionBySubjectID` from data base and the code

```
 public ArrayList<QuestionModel> getQuestionBySubjectID(int subjectId) {
    ArrayList<QuestionModel> questionArrayList = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from Questions where subject_id=" + subjectId, null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        QuestionModel questionModelObject = new QuestionModel();

        questionModelObject.setQuestionId(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("questionId")));
        questionModelObject.setQuestion(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question")));
        questionModelObject.setQuestion(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerOne")));
        questionModelObject.setQuestion(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerTwo")));
        questionModelObject.setQuestion(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerThree")));
        questionModelObject.setQuestion(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerFour")));
        questionModelObject.setAnswerOne(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("correctAnswer")));
        questionArrayList.add(questionModelObject);
        res.moveToNext();
    }


    return questionArrayList;
}
```

Whats wrong with this code? I do not know what is the error (in Cursor).

Comment: maybe something wrong with your query string. be sure that your table `Questions`  and column `subject_id` are spelled correctly.....

Comment: it would be helpfull to see your code where you are initializing the database and table (including the SQL String please)....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your cursor doesn't contain any result. Might be caused by a wrong query.